# sortBy not working (Nothings happen) in my case in laravel5.1

Tags: sorting, laravel-5, collections

I'm trying to use the `sortBy()` of laravel but it has no effect for my situation. I want to sort the `question_number` field in the `question_numbers` table. I'm using `belongsToMany` relationship here. Please see my code for reference:

```
    $undeleted = function($query){
        return $query->where('deleted', 0);
    };

    $quiz = Quiz::with([
        'multiple_choices.question_numbers' => $undeleted
    ])->find($id);

    $quiz_items = collect($quiz->multiple_choices);

    $quiz_items->sortBy(function($quiz_item){
        return $quiz_item['question_numbers.question_number'];
    });

    dd($quiz_items);
```

The result of the code above is just list of multiple choices **without** sorting.

Comment: Are you sure that `$quiz_item['question_numbers.question_number']` has the right value? Try to dd() it and verify that you access the right property.

Comment: @manniL If I try dd() I'm getting a null. Why is that? I have data in my database.

Comment: Looks like you access it wrong. `dd($quiz_item)` and look how the structure is.